# Unexpected and missing keys in state_dict when converting pytorch to onnx

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, pytorch, onnx

When I convert a '.pth' model from PyTorch to ONNX, an error like `Unexpected keys and missing keys` occur.

This is my model:

```
    1 import torch
    2 import torch.onnx
    3 from mmcv import runner
    4 import torch.`enter code here`nn as nn
    5 from mobilenet import MobileNet
    6 # A model class instance (class not shown)
    7 md=MobileNet(1,2)
    8 model = md
    9 device_ids = [0,2,6,7,8]
    10 model = nn.DataParallel(model,device_ids)
    11 #torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = True
    12 # Load the weights from a file (.pth usually)
    13 runner.load_checkpoint(model,'../mmdetection-        master/work_dmobile/faster_rcnn_r50_fpn_1x/epoch_60.pth')
    14 #model = MMDataParallel(model, device_ids=[0])
    15 #state_dict=torch.load('../mmdetection-master/r.pkl.json')
    16 # Load the weights now into a model net architecture defined by our class
    17 #model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    18 #model = runner.load_state_dict(state_dict)
    19 model=runner.load_state_dict({k.replace('module.',' '):v for k,v in state_dict['state_dict'].items()})
    20 # Create the right input shape (e.g. for an image)
    21 dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 64, 512, 256)
    22 
    23 torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, "onnx_model_name.onnx")
```

And this is the error:

```
unexpected key in source state_dict: backbone.stem.0.conv.weight, backbone.stem.0.bn.weight, backbone.stem.0.bn.bias, backbone.stem.0.bn.running_mean, backbone.stem.0.bn.running_var, backbone.stem.0.bn.num_batches_tracked, backbone.stem.1.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.stem.1.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.stem.1.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.stem.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.stem.1.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.stem.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.stem.1.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.stem.1.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.stem.1.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.stem.1.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.stem.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.stem.1.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.stem.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv1.0.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv1.0.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv1.0.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv1.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv1.0.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv1.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv1.0.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv1.0.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv1.0.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv1.0.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv1.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv1.0.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv1.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv1.1.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv1.1.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv1.1.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv1.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv1.1.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv1.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv1.1.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv1.1.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv1.1.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv1.1.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv1.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv1.1.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv1.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv2.0.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv2.0.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv2.0.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv2.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv2.0.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv2.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv2.0.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv2.0.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv2.0.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv2.0.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv2.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv2.0.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv2.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv2.1.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv2.1.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv2.1.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv2.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv2.1.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv2.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv2.1.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv2.1.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv2.1.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv2.1.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv2.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv2.1.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv2.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.0.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.0.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.0.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.0.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.0.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.0.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv3.0.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.0.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.0.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.1.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.1.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.1.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.1.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.1.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.1.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv3.1.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.1.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.1.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.2.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.2.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.2.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.2.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.2.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.2.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.2.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.2.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv3.2.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.2.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.2.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.2.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.2.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.3.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.3.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.3.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.3.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.3.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.3.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.3.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.3.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv3.3.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.3.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.3.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.3.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.3.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.4.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.4.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.4.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.4.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.4.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.4.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.4.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.4.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv3.4.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.4.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.4.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.4.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.4.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.5.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.5.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.5.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.5.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.5.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.5.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv3.5.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv3.5.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv3.5.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv3.5.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv3.5.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv3.5.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv3.5.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv4.0.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv4.0.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv4.0.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv4.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv4.0.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv4.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv4.0.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv4.0.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv4.0.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv4.0.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv4.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv4.0.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv4.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv4.1.depthwise.0.weight, backbone.conv4.1.depthwise.1.weight, backbone.conv4.1.depthwise.1.bias, backbone.conv4.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv4.1.depthwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv4.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, backbone.conv4.1.pointwise.0.weight, backbone.conv4.1.pointwise.0.bias, backbone.conv4.1.pointwise.1.weight, backbone.conv4.1.pointwise.1.bias, backbone.conv4.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, backbone.conv4.1.pointwise.1.running_var, backbone.conv4.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, neck.lateral_convs.0.conv.weight, neck.lateral_convs.0.conv.bias, neck.lateral_convs.1.conv.weight, neck.lateral_convs.1.conv.bias, neck.lateral_convs.2.conv.weight, neck.lateral_convs.2.conv.bias, neck.fpn_convs.0.conv.weight, neck.fpn_convs.0.conv.bias, neck.fpn_convs.1.conv.weight, neck.fpn_convs.1.conv.bias, neck.fpn_convs.2.conv.weight, neck.fpn_convs.2.conv.bias, rpn_head.rpn_conv.weight, rpn_head.rpn_conv.bias, rpn_head.rpn_cls.weight, rpn_head.rpn_cls.bias, rpn_head.rpn_reg.weight, rpn_head.rpn_reg.bias, bbox_head.fc_cls.weight, bbox_head.fc_cls.bias, bbox_head.fc_reg.weight, bbox_head.fc_reg.bias, bbox_head.shared_fcs.0.weight, bbox_head.shared_fcs.0.bias, bbox_head.shared_fcs.1.weight, bbox_head.shared_fcs.1.bias

missing keys in source state_dict: conv2.1.depthwise.1.weight, conv4.0.depthwise.0.weight, conv4.1.pointwise.1.weight, conv3.2.depthwise.0.weight, conv3.1.pointwise.0.weight, conv3.4.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.5.depthwise.1.bias, conv2.1.pointwise.1.weight, stem.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv3.3.pointwise.1.weight, conv3.3.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv3.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv2.1.depthwise.1.running_var, conv1.0.depthwise.1.weight, conv3.5.depthwise.1.running_var, stem.0.bn.bias, conv3.2.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv2.0.depthwise.0.weight, conv2.1.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.1.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.2.pointwise.1.bias, conv2.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, stem.1.pointwise.0.weight, conv2.0.depthwise.1.weight, stem.1.depthwise.0.weight, conv1.1.pointwise.1.weight, conv3.5.pointwise.0.weight, conv3.4.depthwise.1.running_var, conv1.0.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.3.depthwise.1.running_var, conv3.0.pointwise.1.weight, conv4.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv4.1.depthwise.1.running_var, stem.1.depthwise.1.running_var, conv3.0.pointwise.1.running_var, conv3.4.depthwise.0.weight, conv3.4.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv4.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.0.depthwise.1.weight, conv3.3.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv3.2.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv3.1.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.5.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.5.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv3.1.pointwise.1.running_var, conv1.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, stem.1.pointwise.1.bias, conv1.0.depthwise.0.weight, conv3.2.pointwise.0.weight, conv4.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv2.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, stem.1.pointwise.1.weight, conv4.1.depthwise.1.weight, conv4.0.pointwise.0.weight, conv1.1.depthwise.1.bias, conv3.2.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv4.1.depthwise.0.weight, conv3.4.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv1.0.depthwise.1.bias, conv2.0.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.4.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv4.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv2.1.depthwise.1.bias, conv3.2.depthwise.1.weight, conv2.0.pointwise.1.weight, conv1.0.pointwise.0.weight, conv3.1.depthwise.1.running_var, conv2.0.pointwise.1.bias, conv4.0.depthwise.1.bias, conv3.3.pointwise.1.running_var, conv3.4.pointwise.1.weight, conv4.0.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.4.depthwise.1.bias, conv4.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv2.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv1.1.depthwise.1.weight, conv2.0.pointwise.1.running_var, stem.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv3.4.pointwise.1.running_var, stem.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.3.depthwise.1.weight, stem.1.pointwise.1.running_var, conv4.1.depthwise.1.bias, conv3.0.pointwise.1.bias, conv2.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv1.1.pointwise.1.bias, conv4.1.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.2.pointwise.0.bias, conv1.1.pointwise.0.weight, conv1.0.pointwise.1.weight, conv1.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, stem.0.conv.weight, stem.1.depthwise.1.bias, conv3.3.depthwise.0.weight, conv1.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.3.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.2.pointwise.1.running_var, conv3.2.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv3.3.depthwise.1.bias, conv4.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv2.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.0.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv3.1.depthwise.1.weight, conv3.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.1.pointwise.1.weight, conv4.0.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.3.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.4.pointwise.0.weight, stem.1.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.0.depthwise.1.bias, conv1.1.pointwise.0.bias, conv4.0.pointwise.1.running_var, stem.0.bn.weight, conv1.0.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv2.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv4.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv1.1.pointwise.1.running_var, conv2.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv2.0.depthwise.1.running_var, conv3.5.depthwise.1.weight, conv3.0.depthwise.0.weight, conv4.0.depthwise.1.running_mean, stem.0.bn.num_batches_tracked, conv3.3.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv2.1.pointwise.1.running_var, conv3.0.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv1.1.depthwise.1.running_var, conv3.0.depthwise.1.running_var, conv1.0.depthwise.1.running_var, stem.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv4.0.pointwise.1.weight, conv1.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv2.1.depthwise.0.weight, conv1.0.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv1.0.pointwise.1.running_var, conv3.5.pointwise.1.weight, conv3.5.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv3.1.depthwise.1.bias, conv3.1.depthwise.0.weight, conv1.1.depthwise.1.running_mean, conv2.0.pointwise.0.weight, conv4.1.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.2.depthwise.1.running_var, conv3.5.pointwise.0.bias, conv3.4.depthwise.1.weight, conv3.2.depthwise.1.bias, stem.0.bn.running_mean, conv4.0.depthwise.1.running_var, conv1.1.depthwise.0.weight, stem.0.bn.running_var, conv4.1.pointwise.0.weight, conv2.1.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.4.pointwise.0.bias, conv1.0.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.5.pointwise.1.running_var, conv1.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.1.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv2.1.depthwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv2.1.pointwise.0.weight, stem.1.depthwise.1.weight, conv3.5.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.5.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.1.pointwise.1.num_batches_tracked, conv3.2.pointwise.1.weight, conv3.5.depthwise.0.weight, conv3.3.pointwise.0.weight, conv2.0.depthwise.1.bias, conv3.0.pointwise.0.weight, conv3.3.pointwise.1.bias, conv3.4.pointwise.1.running_mean, conv4.0.depthwise.1.weight, conv4.1.pointwise.1.running_var
```

Answer (score 6):

In line 19, try using `model=runner.load_state_dict(..., strict=False)`.

Using the parameter `strict=False` tells the `load_state_dict` function that there might be missing keys in the checkpoint, which usually come from the BatchNorm layer as I see in this case.